# How to copy folder (Via Command prompt) which is contain a space in the name?

Tags: command-line, cmd

if i copy without space (Name Folder), 
example:

```
xcopy /E C:\Test\SQL G:\SQL
```

this copy all content of my folder, Fine!

i dont know how to copy folder if name contain a space, With "xcopy" command.

i found many reviews about space in command prompt and show me solutions like

```
c:\>xcopy /E "c:\Documents\SQL Server Management\" "G:\SQL\"
```

but doesn't work for me.

if I copy a folder where the name contains spaces, the result is: Invalid number of parameters...

Any can help me ?
Tnhks

Comment: what does "doesn't work for me" mean?

Comment: Quotes around a path that includes a space is the standard syntax.

Comment: Error: Invalid number of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You should report the error message you are receiving, what happened when you executed he command (if anything) and what you expected to happen.

Your problem is that `copy` requires a filemask to know which files you require to be copied.

c:>xcopy /E "c:\Documents\SQL Server Management*.*" "G:\SQL\"

specifies that all files with all extensions be copied. The quotes are required to specify "paths\containing spaces" as `xcopy` (or any other command has no way of reading your mind and can't be certain of what `c:\Documents\SQL Server Management\ G:\SQL\` means - is it 'copy c:\Documents\SQL to "Server Management\ G:\SQL\"' or 'copy "c:\Documents\SQL Server" to "Management\ G:\SQL\"' or are sume of what appear to be arguments strays data or what?

Comment: my result is: Invalid number of parameters. i will try your solution. put asterisc after path.